# IIS url rewrite rules to hide subfolders

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, url-rewrite-module

I have 2 .net API projects, servce1 and service2.
I would like to put them both under the same domain (site). I can ensure the APIs routing not overlapping.
I deployed the projects as:

- Default Web Site/

  - service1  (raw url: http://mydomian/service1/api/ONE)
  - service2  (raw url: http://mydomian/service2/api/TWO)

What I want to achieve is that I can use http://mydomain/api/ONE or http://mydomain/api/TWO to access both service1 and service2 APIs without the subfolders in the URL.

I tried using URL rewrite module I got it works for one, but I can not get the second one work, with the same settings. See the setting file below.

I tried moving the rules orders. no luck.

```xml
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="first" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)ONE(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URL}" pattern="(.*)/api/ONE(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/Servuce1/api/ONE{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="seconds" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)TWO(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/api/TWO(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/service2/api/TWO{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

What is wrong with my settings?

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Should the stopProcessing be set to "true", so that the second rule is not applied when the first rule gets matched?